# Thread based TCP and DHCP using freeRTOS

Tags: tcp, embedded, microcontroller, freertos, dhcp

Working on the interrupt-driven interface of W5100S(Ethernet Controller) [Recv, Disconnect, Connect]. System based on TCP server and DHCP client using FreeRTOS. But I'm confused at how to handle DHCP client and TCP Server in threads. Do I need to create individual threads for DHCP & TCP or single thread ?

Also this code only works if there is LAN cable plugged, that I get from PHY status register. Currently my code flow is like below in single task,

```
void taskEthernet(void *arg)
{
    // Initialize seq here
    
    for(;;)
    {
        if(CABLE_PLUGEED)
        {
            // Run DHCP and process further according to DHCP return state
            // DISC, REQ handle by DHCP stack
            
            DHCPState = DHCP_Run();
            
            switch(DHCPState)
            {
                case DHCP_Running: break;
                case DHCP_Failed : break;
                case IP_LEASED: 
                {
                    /*  Interrupt Driven Interface called here
                        Receive data, Recv Disconnect and Connection 
                        established according to socket state */
                        
                        switch(sockState)
                        {
                            case ESTABLISHED:
                            {
                                if(CONNECTED_INT)   // Clear int
                                if(RECV_INT)        // Recv data
                            }
                            break;
                            
                            case DISCONNECT:
                            {
                                if(DICONNECT_INT)   // close socket 
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }
                break;
            
            }
        }
        else // CABLE_UNPLUGGED
        {
            // Close opened sockets
        }
        
        // Here I handle socket open, listen, close, send data cases.
        
        switch(localSockState)
        {
            case OPEN:      // OPEN socket
            case CLOSE:     // CLOSE socket
            case SEND:      // Send Data
            case LISTEN:    // Start Listen 
        }
        
        sleep(100);
    }
```

But this code cause system slow when increasing in sleep time also reducing sleep time cause problem for other tasks.

Suggest me better solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know whether FreeRTOS is pre-emptive (sleep not required) or co-operative (sleep required to let other tasks run) but either way, I would simply run the task once, and reschedule it to run a little before the lease expires.  Why does it have to be run in an endless loop so frequently?

Comment: @tonypdmtr FreeeRTOS is pre-emptive and also I need to run this code endless because any time user can plug LAN and read/write data and unplugged. So I cannot run only once.

Comment: With W5100S you can test either PHYSR0 bit 7 [CABOFF] (preferred) or IC pin #17 [LNKn] to know when you lose physical connection.

Answer (score 0):

Which TCP/IP stack are you using?  If you are using [FreeRTOS's own stack](https://freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/index.html) then it handles DHCP for you.  There is a DCHP callback that enables you to have fine control, but most applications don't use the callback as the standard behaviour is all they need.

Comment: No, I'm not using freeRTOS TCP/IP stack instead of I'm using Wiznet [TCP/IP Stack] (https://github.com/Wiznet/ioLibrary_Driver) for my application.